# Is there any way to replace a wave image and make same wave animation using only css?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, clip-path

I've made this water wave text animation & image animation by using 3 wave images in the background, but i want to replace those 3 background images with only css animations ad clip-path css.

I've used key frame animation to move background images continueosly and clip-path in the text for animation effect like water. I just wanted to replace images not text.

Is it possible ? If yes please help me...

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@600&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}
.text-animation {
  background: #0f0f0f;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.text-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.text-wrapper h2 {
  z-index: 4;
  color: #f0f0f0;
  font-size: 15vw;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -62%);
}

.text-wrapper h2:nth-child(1) {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #f0f0f0;
}

.text-wrapper h2:nth-child(2) {
  color: #fff;
  animation: wave 4s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes wave {
  /* start point */
  0%,
  100% {
    clip-path: polygon(
      0% 46%,
      17% 45%,
      34% 50%,
      56% 61%,
      69% 62%,
      86% 60%,
      100% 51%,
      100% 100%,
      0% 100%
    );
  }
  /* Mid point */
  50% {
    clip-path: polygon(
      0% 59%,
      16% 64%,
      33% 65%,
      52% 61%,
      70% 52%,
      85% 47%,
      100% 48%,
      100% 100%,
      0% 100%
    );
  }
}

/* ********************* Image Waves ************************ */
.waveDiv {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.wave-content-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: -1px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #000000 30%, #002029 90%);
}
.first-wave {
  z-index: 3;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.second-wave {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
.third-wave {
  z-index: 1;
}
.wave-image {
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 bottom;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
}
.first-image {
  background-size: 50% 100px;
}
.animation-wave .first-image {
  animation: move-wave 3s;
  -webkit-animation: move-wave 3s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.second-image {
  background-size: 50% 120px;
}
.animation-wave .second-image {
  animation: waves 10s linear infinite;
}
.third-image {
  background-size: 50% 140px;
}
.animation-wave .third-image {
  animation: waves 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes waves {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0) scaleY(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-25%) scaleY(0.55);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%) scaleY(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-animation">
      <div class="text-wrapper">
        <h2>ALAP</h2>
        <h2>ALAP</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="waveDiv animation-wave">
      <div class="wave-content-wrapper first-wave">
        <div class="wave-image first-image" style="background-image: url('http://front-end-noobs.com/jecko/img/wave-top.png')"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="wave-content-wrapper second-wave">
        <div class="wave-image second-image" style="background-image: url('http://front-end-noobs.com/jecko/img/wave-mid.png')"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="wave-content-wrapper third-wave">
        <div class="wave-image third-image" style="background-image: url('http://front-end-noobs.com/jecko/img/wave-bot.png')"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think using background-images is just fine here. However, you could apply all 3 background-images to the same element...

Comment: Yes @tacoshy, I know that but I want to make something different compared to what I've made. But I've no idea, is there any possibility to do so?

Comment: @AlapJoshi something like this? https://codepen.io/tedmcdo/pen/PqxKXg  I can't take credit as it was the first link after Google searching "wave animation css"

Comment: @Harrison Nice but as you have used an image for the wave, I want to replace that and make the wave using CSS only (In short no images just CSS).

Comment: Have you looked at this https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-wavy-shapes-patterns-in-css/